# Override virtual generic method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, overriding, virtual

I have a generic method like this:

```
public class DomainServiceBase<TEntity> : IDomainServiceBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public virtual async Task<bool> InsertAndSaveAsync<TRequest>(TRequest request)
    {
        // Implementations
    }
}
```

And i override it in another class like this:

```
public class AnnouncementDomainService : DomainServiceBase<AnnouncementDataModel>, IAnnouncementDomainService
{
    public override async Task<bool> InsertAndSaveAsync<AnnouncementAddRequest>(AnnouncementAddRequest request)
    {
        // an example of my issue
        var title =  request.Title // here i get CS1061 error

        // Implementations
    }
}
```

I do not have any access to AnnouncementAddRequest properties.

This is AnnouncementAddRequest model :

```
    public class AnnouncementAddRequest
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public AnnouncementAddRequest()
        {
            Title = string.Empty;
            Code = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, all properties are public
I attach a screenshot from visual studio intelliSense

[image]

I am trying to override virtual generic method in the derived class so I can do validations and at the end, execute `await base.InsertAndSaveAsync(request)`

Comment: Isn't `TRequest` also a type parameter of `DomainServiceBase`?

Comment: At the moment, `DomainServiceBase<AnnouncementDataModel> t = new AnnouncementDomainService(); t.InsertAndSaveAsync(new AbsolutelyAnyTypeOfObject());` is legal, because that's what the base type's method says it can accept. You can't suddenly impose restrictions on what the method will accept in a derived class.

Comment: `<AnnouncementAddRequest>` is a generic parameter, it's the same as `<T>` or `<TRequest>`

Comment: @vc74 no it is not

Comment: @shingo if i remove `<AnnouncementAddRequest>` i get :  no suitable method found to override

Comment: @AryanRiyahi you are trying to specialize the generic method, not override it. `InsertAndSaveAsync<AnnouncementAddRequest>` isn't the same signature as ` `InsertAndSaveAsync<T>`. C# doesn't have generic specialization and it can't be emulated through overriding. As others said, you probably need to make `TRequest` a class type parameter

Comment: BTW the name `InsertAndSaveAsync` is a red flag that you're trying to create a low-level CRUD class. `InsertAndSave` has no business at the domain level. If you use EF, then DbContext already is a *multi-entity high level Unit-of-Work*. It doesn't need to be wrapped in low-level CRUD classes. If your ` InsertAndSaveAsync<AnnouncementAddRequest>` calls `SaveChanges` it will also perform 42 `DELETE Doctors` or 67 `UPDATE Customers` if the UoW detects such changes

Comment: Specifically for `virtual Task<bool> DomainServiceBase.InsertAndSaveAsync<TRequest>`, you're saying that anything derived from `DomainServiceBase` can handle *any request type*. You can't override this with a method that only handles a specific type. That's what specialization means

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that if you specify the method with generic parameters, if you override it in inheriting class, you must keep generic type parameter.

Source of your confusion lies in overriding method declaration, where you have specified:

```
public override async Task<bool> InsertAndSaveAsync<AnnouncementAddRequest>(
    AnnouncementAddRequest request) { ... }
```

Compiler treats `AnnouncementAddRequest` as just another "name" for generic parameter, but it is still generic param, just as `T` or whatever. It's not your class.

Now, once we explained where the problem is, the solution is to add this parameter as generic parameter to your base class, as already mentioned in the other answer.